# Log 4j TimeBasdRollingPolicy with file size limit

Tags: java, log4j

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.R.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.R.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=1024
log4j.appender.R.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=example.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
log4j.appender.R.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=example.log
```

The logging is working fine, but the log file size is not limited to 1024. it keep on increasing.

I want to set the limit file Size limit. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have no settings for size limitations while using TimeBasedRollingPolicy.. 
I have started using the below solution to solve the issue..

```
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.Append=true
log4j.fileName=logs/example
log4j.appender.R.File=${log4j.fileName}.log
log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${log4j.fileName}.%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy.MinIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy.MaxIndex=13
log4j.appender.R.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.R.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=400000000
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c <%X{currentUser}> - %m%n
```

Comment: If I used log4j.appender.R.RollingPolicy.MaxIndex. How long will it take for old files to be deleted?